# how many times will a function be executed?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop

I have this piece of code

```
for ( i = 0; i < N ; i+=3 ){
   foo();
   if( i % 5 ==0) foo();
}
```

and i am to decide how many times will be foo() executed. I have this options

```
ceil(N/3)+floor(N/5)
ceil(N/3)+ceil(N/5)
floor((N+2)/3)+floor((N+14)/15)
floor(N/3)+floor(N/5)
floor(N/3)+ceilt(N/5)
```

what is the right way for deciding the right outcome? Outer loop executes foo() outside of condition N/3 times , but how to decide how many times will condition execute the function?

Comment: Try working through it with a few different values of N - it soon becomes apparent which one is the correct answer. (Note also that you appear to have some typos, e.g. `ceilt` and `foor`, which you might want to fix.)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it easier to understand we can split this cycle into 2:

```
for ( i = 0; i < N ; i += 3 ){
   foo();
}

for ( i = 0; i < N ; i += 15 ){
   foo();
}
```

For any natural *N* and *K* cycle *(i=0; i< N; i += k)* will run *1 + floor((N - 1)/k)* times.

This way total number of runs will be:
*1 + floor( (N-1) / 3)* for first and *1 + floor( (N-1) / 15)* for second cycle which is:

```
2 + floor((N-1) / 3) + floor((N-1) / 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the loop would be

```
for ( i = 0; i < N ; i+=3 ){
   foo();
}
```

then it would execute approximately N/3 times (floor((N+2/3)) to be exact). If the loop would be

```
for ( i = 0; i < N ; i+=3 ){
   if( i % 5 ==0) foo();
}
```

then it would execute approximately N/15 times (floor((N+14)/15) to be exact), since

- you enter in the loop only if `i` is a multiple of 3,
- but foo is executed only if `i` is a multiple of 5;
- so combined; foo is only executed if `i` is a multiple of 3 **and** a multiple of 5; thus only if it is a multiple of 15.

So by some very simple deductions; the correct answer is the sum of both.

```
floor((N+2)/3)+floor((N+14)/15)
```

Comment: @johnyb: any update on this? Did our answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy way to see how the different formulas work is to write a function for each in excel, and then feed them different values for N, and then compare the result to some values for N that you calculate by hand.

As already observed earlier, the second call to foo() will only be performed when i % 5 is 0. Since i is stepped by 3, this will only be executed every 15th iteration, since 15 is the smallest number that is divisible by both 3 and 5. This should make it possible to exlude some of the formulas.